# PHP Package installation error

Tags: 16.04, php

When I install PHP this error occurs:

```
Package 'php5-gd' has no installation candidate
```

Additional output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: 16.04 does not have PHP 5, only PHP 7.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is easy:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php-mysql
```

16.04 LTS comes now with php 7.0 and the names of the whole packages including the virtual packages have changed to be now `php-*` or `php7.0-*` instead of `php5-*`.

Comment: This showed up in LQ review. You should probably mention that `php5-*` package are now mostly known as `php-*` and they;re for PHP 7.